# Incrementing Folder Names such as 5.0.0.x in C#

Tags: c#

I have a folder ~/ConfigurationDirectory. The sub-folders within this folder are named as follows

5.0.0.1
5.0.0.2
5.0.0.3
...

Now, the requirement is that - Identify the folder which has the "largest" name numerically and create a copy of the folder. Rename the new folder as 5.0.0.n+1 (assuming that the largest numerically available folder is 5.0.0.n)

I have written code which will identify the largest named folder. Also, I have written the code which will do the copy of folder and sub-folders. What I am not able to get is, how do I get the name of the new folder, i.e., 5.0.0.n+1

How do I do this in C#? Any pointers would suffice rather than complete coding.

Thanks!

Comment: I see you've marked an answer as accepted, but it's wrong :D (or at least much nastier than needed).  Take a look at abatishchev's answer, and then use the right tool for the job: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602229/incrementing-folder-names-such-as-5-0-0-x-in-c/3602651#3602651

Comment: @STW: Why do you assume these are version numbers? He never said that in the question.

Comment: @Mark -- good point, but methinks we all are assuming it's a Version number (otherwise you woulda pointed this out 3-hours ago)  ;) -- if you edit your answer I'll remove my downvote, it's locked at the moment though

Comment: @STW: Fair enough. I've clarified my answer for you.

Comment: STW: A little bit of background - By default, the product creates folder 5.0.0.0 and when I create a new instance (say, a Development Instance of the Product on the same server), I need to create a folder 5.0.0.1 and then modify a few configuration files. Since, modification of Config files is prone to error, I started writing this utility. So, honestly, I do not know if they are version numbers and tomorrow if the product, by default, creates folders such as 5.0.0.0.0, then the Version.TryParse method would fail. PS: I have not updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Mark: +1 for reading my question as I have written. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the numbers you're working with are not simple four-part version numbers, you're going to want to use the string.Split() to break up the folder name, and then Convert.ToInt32() or int.Parse() to turn the last chunk into a number. From there, you increment it, and then use something like string.Format() to turn it back into a folder name.

If, however, you are indeed working with simple version numbers, then using the `System.Version` class (specifically, the `Parse()` or `TryParse()` and `ToString()` methods) would be a significantly more straightforward implementation.

Comment: Why do all this, when you can just use `System.Version.TryParse()`? ;-)

Comment: @STW: Certainly in this specific case, that would work very well. Right up until you overflowed the Int16 chunks that System.Version uses (yeah, we did it...).

Comment: lol, if you've got the development-force to warrant 32k versions of an application then I guess I would find it acceptable to task someone with writing your own `Version` structure.  Did you at least jump right to `Int64` so that you're clear for a while longer?

Comment: @STW: -1 for lack of imagination. In our particular case, we were using the revision number from our source repository as the 4th number. As soon as we hit 32k revisions in our source repository, it failed.

Comment: at least you've got a better explanation than "we got out build server stuck in a loop for a month".  And, to be fair, you've got a solid case for reinventing the wheel--but I wouldn't assume it's a case where most people would need to avoid `System.Version`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `string.LastIndexOf` for this purpose (this is much more light-weight than using `string.Split`):

```
static string GetNextFolderName(string folderName)
{
    int lastDotPosition = folderName.LastIndexOf('.');
    string lastPartOfFolderName = folderName.Substring(lastDotPosition + 1);

    int number;
    if (int.TryParse(lastPartOfFolderName, out number))
    {
        number++;
        return folderName.Substring(0, lastDotPosition + 1) + number.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        // You've got a problem on your hands, here.
        throw new FormatException();
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: It has been pointed out that this approach is perhaps excessive in light of the existence of [`Version.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.tryparse.aspx). A few points in response to that:

1. `Version.TryParse` is available as of .NET 4.0. Many developers are not using .NET 4.0; therefore to discard any alternative approach right out is (in my opinion) quite narrow-sighted.
2. It has not been indicated whether performance is much of a concern. Presumably, it is not. However, when you think about the problem conceptually, `Version.TryParse` is actually doing significantly more work than we need in this case: it is looking at every individual component of the version string and parsing them all into a complete [`Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) object. The approach outlined above, on the other hand, only bothers to examine the last *part* of the version string, and is therefore more efficient. I have [verified this](http://pastebin.com/YcqLrV1N): using the approach above executes in about 30% of the time it takes using `Version.TryParse`.
3. Of course it is fair to point out that, if one already knew of `Version.TryParse` and chose to write the above code anyway, one would be guilty of premature optimization. That said, suppose you did *not* know about it, and you *already wrote* the above code. Would the right thing to do be to refactor the code to use `Version.TryParse`, keeping the same functionality and slowing performance by about 200%? I'm not asking rhetorically; perhaps in some cases, for the sake of simplicity and maintainability, it might be. But it would be a judgment call.

I post these points primarily as a rebuttal to anyone who would immediately dismiss a solution simply because it performs the same task as an "out-of-the-box" solution. Sometimes, depending on your circumstances, it can make sense to do something yourself anyway. Just know what you're getting yourself into, and be ready to take a step back and change direction if and when it becomes appropriate to do so.

Comment: Dan: Perfect. Thanks for the complete code. I wrote something similar.

Comment: Why do all this, when you can just use `System.Version.TryParse()`? ;-)

Comment: @STW: Guh... because I didn't know about `System.Version.TryParse`? ;) But to offer a couple more legitimate reasons: also because it's only in .NET 4.0 (which probably explains why I didn't know about it), and also because this version is more efficient, as `Version.TryParse` collects more information than we are using here.

Comment: @Dan: "Supported in: 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0"

Comment: @STW: Reference? I am looking at the MSDN documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.tryparse.aspx. Also, trying to use `Version.TryParse` with my target framework set to 3.5 in Visual Studio causes a compile error for me. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @STW: Also, you may be interested in reading my update. (You may also find my points to be ridiculous -- who knows? In any case, I feel that there is a larger potential discussion here than simply "Use `Version.TryParse`; end of story.")

Comment: whoops!  Good catch--looks like `TryParse()` was just added in .NET 4 (my reference of 1.0 - 4.0 was for the `System.Version` class; could have sworn that I was using that back in 2.0 :-S

Comment: ...and +1, btw.  For the Fx version catch (not the performance-aspect, my $.02 is that even if it's faster the benefit would be infinitesimal small)

Answer (score 3):

This is the most correct solution, imo:

```
Version version;
if (Version.TryParse("5.0.0.0", out version))
{
    // your logic here
    return new Version(
         version.Major,
         version.Minor,
         version.Build,
         version.Revision + 1).ToString();
    // will return 5.0.0.1
}
else
{
    // error handling here
}
```

Comment: I hate to see hand-rolled methods when .NET already gives you exactly the tool for the job :D

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    static class Extensions
    {
        public static TOutput[] ToArray<TSource, TOutput>(this IEnumerable<TSource> col, Converter<TSource, TOutput> converter)
        {
            return Array.ConvertAll<TSource, TOutput>(col.ToArray(), converter);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string original = "5.0.0.0";
            int[] tmp = original.Split('.').ToArray<string, int>(new Converter<string, int>(delegate(string s)
            {
                int result;
                return int.TryParse(s, out result) ? result : 0;
            }));

            tmp[tmp.Length - 1]++;
            // re should contain 5.0.0.1
            string re = String.Join(".", tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do all this, when you can just use `System.Version.TryParse()`? ;-)

Answer (score -1):

It's a simple algorithm, which can be applied to any number of elements:

1. Split the string on the dots. Call the resulting array `a`.
2. Convert the last element of a to an integer. Call this integer `i`.
3. `i++`
4. `a[last] = i.ToString()`
5. Join the elements of `a` using a dot as the separator.

Make sure that your identification algorithm really does select the numerically largest value: if you have 5.0.0.9 and 5.0.0.10, then you would find 5.0.0.9 if the identification really uses alphabetic ordering.

Comment: Michael Madsen: Spot on, my identification algorithm picked up 5.0.0.9 instead of 5.0.0.10. I will have to revisit it. I do not have 15 points to upvote your answer, however, the day I get 15 votes, I promise that I will upvote your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Why do all this, when you can just use `System.Version.TryParse()`? ;-)

Comment: @STW: You can use System.Version for this particular case, but if you have 5 elements, you can't. If you have less than 4, you need to access a different field of the Version structure. Doing it "manually" is more flexible and reusable.

Comment: fair enough, also found out that `System.Version.TryParse()` is new to .NET 4, and that the OP never explicitly said anything about these being version numbers.  If you edit your post I can remove my downvote